# Nginx + Magento configuration problems. PHP files are being downloaded

Tags: php, magento, nginx, configuration, vhosts

I've been fighting to get Magento to run on Nginx. 
I'm not an expert at this but I've been troubleshooting with my Vhost configurations for weeks.

Right now I've gotten to a point where I simply don't know what to change anymore.
The problem is that whenever I enter my index at https://mailtest.unitracer.nl/ and navigate to Magento it tries to download PHP files. 
This project has to be finished, I’m an intern at a company where I really want to learn how to implement Nginx, no one can help me with it here, so I really hope the people here can help me out!
I build two seperate vhost files in nginx, one for my index and some back-up folder that I write backups to so I can download them.
The other one is purely for Magento.

I'll post both of them here including my nginx.conf file.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    #default_type text/html;
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here is my magento vhost file:

```
    server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name mailtest.unitracer.nl www.mailtest.unitracer.nl;


          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/magento.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/magento.error.log; 


    root /var/www/magento;

    location  / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    #deny deze mappen, niemand heeft er iets te zoeken
    location /app/ { deny all; }
    location /includes/ { deny all; }
    location /lib/ { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location /var/ { deny all; }

    #in /var/export map moet ik user credentials instellen om /var/export te benaderen
    #in htpasswd
    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex on;
    }

    #Deny access hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
    }


    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }


    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

        location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        expires 30d;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here is my other vhost, i'm not even sure if I need this one but my index won't show without it.

```
server {
        listen 80;
    listen 443;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php;
        autoindex on;

        server_name mailtest.unitracer.nl;

#SSL Directives
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

#Location for index
#   location ^(.+~\.php)(/.*)$ {
#                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+~\.php)(/.+)$;
#              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#                fastcgi_index index.php;
#       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#               include fastcgi_params;
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
#        }

    #Mijn back-up server block
location /backups {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /var/www/backups/.htpasswd;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

I know that PHP files have been passed to the correct PHP FPM socket because it worked with phpmyadmin before.

It would be great if someone could help me with the configuration of this problem, I really need magento to work so that I understand how to host it on Nginx!

Friendly greetings,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is mistake - missing \

```
location ~ \.php$ {

 expires 30d;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
fastcgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove index index.php on location / and set index index.php under servername and it will work it is also possible that you need to add fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$; and fastcqi_index index.php
at locationa ~ .php$